# How to create a basic UDP listener with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, udp

Being new to both Spring and UDP, I have spent a lot of time on researching this subject without finding a good answer. I need to build a listener that potentially can handle large amounts of messages and forward them to Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with a solution that uses java.net datagram classes in a Spring ApplicationRunner component implementation.